# C++ If / Else If / Else Block - Always Falls Through to Else Block

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

Here a C/C++ snippet that is causing issues for me.  For some reason, the code always drops into the 'else' block, even if the conditions in the 'if' or 'else if' blocks are true.  If I replace the 'else' block with another 'else if' block-- the code in the previous 'if' or 'if else' block will run just fine (if the condition is true)!  The code in the first two blocks will also run if I just delete the last block completely.

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

```
for (i = 0; i < text_len; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        if (text[i] == alphabet[j])
        {
            coded_text[i] = cipher[j];
        }
        else if(text[i] == (alphabet[j] - 32))
        {
            coded_text[i] = (cipher[j] - 32);
        }
        else
        {
            coded_text[i] = text[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not productive to comment on incomplete code snippets.

Comment: Please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to convert to lower-case then use [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower). I also recommend you check out e.g. [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I neglected to break out of the inner loop if a true condition was found.

```
for (i = 0; i < text_len; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        if (text[i] == alphabet[j])
        {
            coded_text[i] = cipher[j];
            break;
        }
        else if(text[i] == (alphabet[j] - 32))
        {
            coded_text[i] = (cipher[j] - 32);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            coded_text[i] = text[i];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### First C and C++ are *different* [programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language), with different specifications.

For C, read its specification (C11 standard) on [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf).

For C++, read its specification (C++11 standard) on [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

#### You should also be interested by [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) C and C++ reference website.

**You'll need to read books** (different ones) **to learn each of these languages**. If you learn C, read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). If you learn C++, read [*Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Notice that C and C++ have different syntax and [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)). Even worse, the semantics of a line of C++ is different of its semantics as a C line (and your example could be both C or C++ code), since C++ has [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) and overloading.

### Use a debugger to understand the behaviour of your programs

If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as your compiler (**read its documentation** and notice that it can compile both C and C++ code) you could compile your code with all warnings and debug info.

For a C file (actually [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) `foo.c` you would compile it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g foo.c` (probably adding `-c -o foo.o` to get some [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) `foo.o`)

For a C++ file (translation unit) `bar.cc` you would compile it with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g bar.cc` (probably adding `-c -o bar.o` to get some [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) `bar.o`)

Later, you would use a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) to get your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (and you could even, with some care, mix C and C++ code). That linker could be [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), and you need to read its documentation.

In practice, **you are likely to use some *additional* software [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing))** in addition to the [standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_library) of your language (notice C and C++ have *different* standard libraries). In particular, most operating systems provide some OS-specific library and [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API). Be aware of [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) and of the [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). You might want to use some [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) if you want to code a [GUI application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface). You could be interested in cross-platform frameworks like [GTK](https://gtk.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), etc...

Once you believe your code is correct, consider enabling compiler optimizations (e.g. by adding `-O2` to compilation commands)

Be sure to get no warnings from the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, so improve your source code till there is none.

Then learn about the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger (read its documentation)

In some cases, some of your C or C++ code could be generated (by tools like [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/)).

You could find [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools (like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) to help you build your executable. Be sure to read their documentation before using them.

There are lots of best practices coding rules involved. I recommend studying (and perhaps contributing to) some *existing* open source project. You'll learn a lot by doing so.

### Consider then looking inside the code of [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software

Such as projects published on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/). You will learn a big lot by looking inside some of them (e.g. inside the code of  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), of the [fish](https://fishshell.com/) shell, of [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), etc...)

**Consider using some [static source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tool** like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).